# Prototype in javascript not working as excepted

Tags: javascript, oop, prototype

I'm very confused about prototype in javascript.

I have this code:

```
  function Animal(name){
  this.name=name;}

  function Dog(nameA){
  this.legs=4;}

  Dog.prototype=new Animal();


 var dog=new Dog();
 alert(Object.getPrototypeOf(dog));
 alert '[object Object]'    

 alert(dog._proto_);
 //alert 'undefined'
```

it's  shouldn't alert 'Animal' twice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use

```
dog.__proto__
```

not

```
dog._proto_
```

JsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gaE3y/

```
function Animal(name){
  this.name=name;}

  function Dog(nameA){
  this.legs=4;}

  Dog.prototype=new Animal();


 var dog=new Dog();
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(dog));
console.log(dog.__proto__);
```

The output in the js fiddle is

```
Animal {name: undefined}
Animal {name: undefined}
```

Comment: OK now its alert [object Object] its not should alert [object Animal]?

Comment: Please, check the jsfiddle to see the exact output. Also have in mind that if use alert the object is cast to a string. And in JavaScript everything is an object.

Comment: @Krasimir how about a _TypeError: undefined is not an object_ then? :)

Comment: Where is this error coming from. The jsfiddle doesn't have it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use two underscores:

```
alert(dog.__proto__);
```

Please see [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto) for details. Also note, that `__proto__` is non-standard as of (current) ECMAScript 5.

Answer (score 0):

`alert` calls `toString()` method of an argument, that is passed, so:

```
var anyObject = {};
alert(anyObject); //[object Object]
console.log(anyObject); // Object {}
console.log(anyObject.toString()) //"[object Object]"
```

Use `console.log` instead of `alert` for clear debugging.

**P.S.:** and, yes, it is `__proto__` instead of `_proto_`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's better way to access prototype.
It is a standard way.

```
dog.constructor.prototype
```